# Placement of participle in a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, participles

How to place a Participle, before the word (noun, adjective,adverb) which is modified by it or after that word. As participle can work like an adjective and an Adverb for modifying.

a. He saw a burning train(here participle is before the noun).

b. The shouting and joy expressed by all is past imagination(here expressed comes after Joy).

c. I have all the qualifications required for the exams(here required comes after qualifications).

d. I have all the required qualifications for the exams.

e. The woman watched the cat creeping toward the bird.

And, is there any difference between the meaning of C and D?

Comment: For most purposes, **c** and **d** are equivalent and interchangeable (but **c** [is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+required+qualifications%2Cthe+qualifications+required&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20required%20qualifications%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20qualifications%20required%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20required%20qualifications%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20qualifications%20required%3B%2Cc0)). Arguably *sometimes* (ever so slightly "marked") **d** might imply they are more "universally known, standard" requirements.

Comment: *I saw a train burning* places more emphasis on the ***action*** (what the train was ***doing***), where *I saw a burning train* focuses more on the ***state, condition*** of the train. But for most purposes they're just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: A guy told me that in 'I saw a burning train' burning is an adjective...and in 'I saw a train burning' , train burning here is written in a noun- verb formation. But even if it came after the noun , it is ultimately an adjective ?   I've understood that their placement is just based on what thing a person wants to emphasise.

Comment: If I compare 1: ***I saw a galloping unicorn*** to 2: ***I saw a unicorn galloping***, I'd have to say the first version was very slightly "weird". More information might be available from the full context, but if I really had nothing else to go on I'd probably assume that version #1 carried the implication *[some] **unicorns rarely / can't  gallop.***